# Carousel or Merry-go round or Move Images in orbit like way in same Activity

Tags: android

I was searching this from long time as I wanted to do some crazy revolving of images in same activity then I found the blog which has explained it in a lot detail and I thought it to share with the stackoverflow. It took me so much time to think about how to make images revolve in orbit like way in same activity and thanks to the blog author. He has shared his code on google code and it contains the link of blog too.

here is the link of code: 
https://code.google.com/p/android-carousel-demo/

I hope it will help to many. Just go through it and his blog also its amazing to know the Coverflow widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one more link for the great explanation. I guess the same author

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel